# issue in showing Websocket response data in existing Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I need help in fixing a bug in my react app.

I am accessing data using websocket in react js, but when i show data in my loop based components it only returns value for single product but i want to show in loop based on multiple product and as per their correct values.

```
client.onmessage = (messageEvent) => {
  const msg = JSON.parse(messageEvent.data)
  const text = JSON.parse(msg.data)
  const auction = text.message
  const eventId = text.event
  const auctionUuid = auction.uuid 
  console.log(eventId) 
  console.log(text)
  console.log(auction)
  if (auctionUuid == this.props.uuid) {
    this.setState({
     auctionUuid: auctionUuid,
     auctionTitle: auctionTitle,
     totalBidAmount: auctionTotalBidAmount,
     userBidAmount: bidAmount,
     bidUsername: user,
     bidExpireDate: auctionBidExpireDate,
     webSocketAuctions: auction,
     counter: 9,
   }) 
    
  } else {
    console.log('uuid is not matched')
  }  
 }
```

Comment: Can you post more details here?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just build the table structure in back end. pass the message as single text type.Like this[REF 1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3IBg.png)

Comment: You should not link an image to code, rather paste the code in the answer itself.